# ¿Cómo comparar Texto en archivo txt?

Tags: java

Mi consulta es la siguiente me dejaron un trabajo de un sistema de vuelos, tengo que validar si hay un vuelo directo y esa parte me funciona donde tengo muchos problemas es a la hora de de validar si hay escalas y mostrarlas.

Agradeceria demasiado si me ayudaran.

```
 public void tablaPasajero(JTable tb, File archivo, String aerosalida, String aerollegada, String fechaSalida, String fechallegada) {
    boolean existe = false;
    int contaEs = 0;
    String[] titulos = {"ID  Aerolinea",
        "Precio vuelo", "Fecha y hora salida",
        "Aeropuerto salida", "Fecha y hora llegada", "Aeropuerto llegada","Hora total"};
    DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel(null, titulos);
    String datos = "";

    
       try {
        BufferedReader archi = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(archivo));

        while ((datos = archi.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] palabra = datos.split(",");

            if (palabra[5].equals(aerosalida) && palabra[8].equals(aerollegada)
                    && palabra[3].equals(fechaSalida) && palabra[6].equals(fechallegada)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hay un vuelo directo para su viaje");
                String fila[] = {palabra[1],  palabra[2],
                    palabra[3] + palabra[4], palabra[5], palabra[6] + palabra[7],
                    palabra[8],palabra[15]};
                Arrays.sort(palabra);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Arrays.toString(palabra));
                existe = true;
                modelo.addRow(fila);

            }
            if (palabra[5].equals(aerosalida)&& palabra[3].equals(fechaSalida) &&
                    palabra[8].equals(aerosalida)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hay una escala para su viaje");
                String fila[] = {palabra[1], palabra[2],
                    palabra[3] + palabra[4], palabra[5], palabra[6] + palabra[7],
                    palabra[8],palabra[15]};
                
                modelo.addRow(fila);

            } else if (palabra[8].equals(aerollegada)&& palabra[6].equals(fechallegada)
                    && palabra[5].equals(aerollegada)){

                String fila[] = {palabra[1],  palabra[2],
                    palabra[3] + palabra[4], palabra[5], palabra[6] + palabra[7],
                    palabra[8],palabra[15]};

                
                existe = true;
                modelo.addRow(fila);
            }

        }
        if (!existe) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No HAY NINGUN VUELO EN ESAS FECHAS");
        }

        tb.setModel(modelo);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR " + e);
    }

}
```

Comment: Cuál es (o son) el problema? "Muchos problemas" no es muy diciente. Qué debería hacer y qué hace en su lugar? Con qué datos debemos probar? PD. Llenar la pregunta con cualquier caracter para saltarte los filtros no es buena idea: están ahí por algo (como puedes ver, tu pregunta está incompleta y eso es lo que buscan evitar)

Comment: Ahora bien, qué tiene que ver el título con el contenido de la pregunta? Crees que en eso radica tu problema? Por qué lo crees?

Comment: Si es que estoy empezando en esto, necesito ayuda para solucionar ese problema

Comment: El problema es cuando busco un viaje y no hay vuelo directo se dispara un mensaje donde me indica que encontro una escala el las encuentra, pero también me muestra demas coincidencias que no tiene nada que ver con lo que yo busque o el usuario busque

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente tu problema puede ser que estas usando una condicion no totalmente excluyente (mas de una condicion pueden agregar filas, incluso la misma fila), solo debes cambiar el segundo `if` por `else if` para asegurar que cada condicion se cumpla por si misma:

```
if (condicion1){
   modelo.addRow(fila);
}
else if(condicion2){
   modelo.addRow(fila);
}else if(condicion3){
   modelo.addRow(fila);
}
```

Comment: Tal vez me ayuda cuando busco un vuelo y no hay escalas me aparecen algunos que solo tiene tiene que ver con el aeropuerto de salida o el llegada como valido para que solo aparescan o directo o escala